# no custom background - touchdragged method?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am beginner in libgdx and trying to experiment .I am using the simple example [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp) .So, I  have 2 questions:

1) I want to use my background picture.So, I have a class Assets where I have all the assets.And I use:

```
public static void load () {
        background = loadTexture("background.png");
        backgroundRegion = new TextureRegion(background, 0, 0, 800, 480);

        ...
        dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png"));
        ...
```

In GameScreen class:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
....
public GameScreen (Game game) {
        this.game = game;

   // create the camera and the SpriteBatch
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

     // create a Rectangle to logically represent the bucket
          bucket = new Rectangle();
....
public void draw (float deltaTime) {
         // Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
          Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

          // tell the camera to update its matrices.
          camera.update();

          batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

          // begin a new batch and draw the bucket and all drops
          batch.begin();
...
```

The problem is that the background doesn't appear (I have it in assets folder as the other files and it is 800x480 pixels).

2) Using

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
             Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
             touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
```

the bucket appears where i press the screen.
If I want to make bucket movement smooth,to drug it, I realize that I must use event handling and inputprocessor [as here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent).

But I can't find a way to make it work.
I mean , I must create a class  MyInputProcessor like the above , then at my drop class (main class) do :

```
public class Drop extends Game {
   @Override
   public void create() {

            Settings.load();
        Assets.load();

        MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);

        setScreen(new GameScreen(this));
```

and then?
How should I use it?

Right now I have in GameScreen class:

```
public void draw (float deltaTime) {
         // Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
          Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       
         ...

          // process user input
          if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
             Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
             touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
             camera.unproject(touchPos);
             bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
             bucket.y = touchPos.y - 64 / 2;
          }
```

Also , the MyInputProcessor gives

> "The type MyInputProcessor must implement the inherited abstract
>   method   InputProcessor.mouseMoved(int, int)"

and at touchMoved

> The method touchMoved(int, int) of type MyInputProcessor must
>   override or implement a   supertype method

I want to use

> touchDragged

inside GameScreen class?or in MyInputProcessor?How should I do it?

Thank you!

-----------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------------

```
import com.badlogic.drop.GameScreen;
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {

    GameScreen fromgamescreen;

    private Vector3 v = new Vector3(0,0,0);
...
@Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
           v.x = screenX;
           v.y = screenY;
           fromgamescreen.camera.unproject(v);
           fromgamescreen.bucket.x = v.x - 64 / 2;
           fromgamescreen.bucket.y = v.y - 64 / 2;
           return true;


       }
```

Comment: Hi George, while using this site try, please, to keep one question per post. It makes for much better answering and searching since the site intends to be a q/a searchable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the draw method, you need to call `batch.draw(backgroundRegion,x,y);` to draw the background. Call it after beginning the batch, but before drawing the drops and the bucket.

2) To get rid of the two warnings, change `touchMoved` to `mouseMoved`.

Polling, rather than event-based input handling, is probably adequate for your game. However, if you want to use an InputProcessor, you would get rid of this code:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
             Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
             touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
             camera.unproject(touchPos);
             bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
             bucket.y = touchPos.y - 64 / 2;
          }
```

and in the input processor, you would have something like:

```
    private Vector3 v = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    //you don't want to recreate this vector every time an event comes in: that wastes memory
    ...
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            v.x = screenX;
            v.y = screenY;
            camera.unproject(v);
            bucket.x = v.x - 64 / 2;
            bucket.y = v.y - 64 / 2;
            return true;
        }
```

To do it this way, the input processor would need references to the camera and bucket.

Comment: :Ok, for the background.For referencing the bucket for example how should I do it?Thanks!

Comment: you could pass the camera and bucket in through the constructor, or you could pass the game screen in and create methods to access the camera and bucket.

Comment: :I did that but now the bucket doesn't appear.In the place where I remove the "if(Gdx.input.isTouched())",should I put sth ?Or the touchDragged is been called "automatically"?

Comment: :Am I doing sth wrong?Check my update please,thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why that doesn't work. The problem might be in your rendering code. I can't write the entire application for you.

Comment: :Of course not!What I did above is right though?And I don't need to put sth in place of "if(Gdx.input.isTouched())" to call MyInputProcessor?

Comment: if it's set as the input processor you do not need to call the events manually.

Comment: :When you say "If it is set as Input processor"?I have "public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor".Do I need sth else?

Comment: I was talking about this line of code: Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);

Comment: :Ok, but how should I use it?I mean , we removed the "if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {...".How should I implement "Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor)"now?Thanks!

Comment: Call it when the screen is loaded.that's it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9222/discussion-between-george-and-ian-markowitz)